# jq: print key and value for each entry in an object when you have multiple values

Tags: jquery, json, jq

```
{
   "host1": [
       {"ip": "10.1.2.3"}, 
       {"ip": "10.2.3.4"}, 
       {"ip": "10.3.4.5"},
   ],
   "host2": [
       {"ip":"10.1.2.2"}, 
       {"ip":"10.4.5.6"},
   ],
   "host3": [
       {"ip":"10.1.18.1"}
   ]
}
```

I'm borrowing most of the structure from another question but changing it since now an entry can have multiple values.

I want the output of the jq to be

```
host1  10.1.2.3
host1  10.2.3.4
host1  10.3.4.5
host2  10.1.2.2
host2  10.4.5.6
host3  10.1.18.1
```

host1 and host2 and printed for each value.

My attempt was:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value[].ip] | @tsv' file.json
```

but the output of that was

```
host1  10.1.2.3  10.2.3.4  10.3.4.5
host2  10.1.2.2  10.4.5.6
host3  10.1.18.1
```

But I want them on separate lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the ips individually to a variable to reference it inside the array:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | .value[].ip as $ip | [.key, $ip] | @tsv'
```

```json
host1   10.1.2.3
host1   10.2.3.4
host1   10.3.4.5
host2   10.1.2.2
host2   10.4.5.6
host3   10.1.18.1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iEKvbHmwgHW)

---

Instead of `to_entries` you can also use `keys_unsorted` to get access to the keys:

```bash
jq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $key | .[$key][] | [$key, .ip] | @tsv'
```

```json
host1   10.1.2.3
host1   10.2.3.4
host1   10.3.4.5
host2   10.1.2.2
host2   10.4.5.6
host3   10.1.18.1
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FYrcvT3sUkx)